# iOS apps two way data exchange

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I basically need to do some data exchange between two iOS apps. These two apps coming from two different team in the same company, but unfortunately they can't be in the same app group.

These two appss need to be able to work offline, which mean I can't exchange the data via backend server.

I know the custom URL scheme is the possible solution. But I can't find a way to post back the response to the calling app, for example I have A app and B app:

1) A app openURL on B app, passing data to B app

2) B app processing the data and generate a file (10 to 20 mb)

3) B app is closed and A app obtain the result (file) generated by B app.

Is there any way to achieve the requirement above?

Comment: does multipeer connection suit your needs?

Comment: B app would just call url scheme of A passing in the data as a url parameter. I’m not sure what the maximum url size is though.

Comment: @Darren, I had this idea in the beginning, thought it doesn't work because B app will close, that's why I can't call url scheme on A, but I could possibly call it before B app is closed, let me give it a try.

Comment: Url schemes launch the app, so it doesn’t matter if it closes. If you’re worried about it losing state, maybe use the URLs to keep track of the state too so you can relaunch the app to the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an action extension in app B then a share sheet in app A.
App A would let App B’s action extension perform some action on some data from App A.

https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/